# PrimeFaces (JSF) Layout in panel grid component

Tags: jsf, layout, primefaces

I'm trying to create a Layout in a Panel Grid Component and somehow it just doesn't work. Has somebody got any Idea where the problem is and any advice how to do it better?

Here my source code:

```
<p:tab id="tab3" title="One of a few tabs">
<h:panelGrid>
    <p:layout>
        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <h:outputText value="Some other components" />
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="north">
            <h:outputText value="Some other components" />
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="west">
            <h:outputText value="Some other components" />
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="east">
            <h:outputText value="Some other components" />
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Thanks for any Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `panelGrid`; use `panelGroup` instead, and the page will display correctly. Another mistake in this code fragment is that:

```
<p:tab id="tab3" title="One of a few tabs">
```

is missing:

```
</p:tab>
```